# How to add negative numbers in a dictionary loop?

Tags: python

I am getting really odd results from this and it's simple math. I must be missing something and as a newbie, I'm sure that's the case.

I pull records from a database of product sales and need to format the results in a number of dictionaries to get this into Excel. I've simplified the example, but the idea is that the `default` dictionary has far more attributes and we create a number of different groupings of product sales based on the attribute.

```
products = {}

for item in records:

    units = int(item['quantity'])
    weight = float(item['weight'])

    print(item['name'] + ' adding: ' + str(weight))

    default = {'sku': item['sku'],
                'product_name': item['name'],
                'units': units,
                'weight': weight}

    if item['sku'] in products:
        if units < 0:
            products[item['sku']]['units']  -= abs(units)
            products[item['sku']]['weight'] -= abs(weight)
        else:
            products[item['sku']]['units']  += (units)
            products[item['sku']]['weight'] += (weight)
    else:
        products[item['sku']] = default

    products[item['sku']]['weight'] = round(products[item['sku']]['weight'], 4)
    print(item['name'] + ' total: ' + str(products[item['sku']]['weight']))
```

If the product is not in the dictionary yet, I add it with a default secondary dictionary as it's value.

The next time we encounter that product, I'd like to add the number of units sold and the total weight. Different products have different weights, so having a running total per product works.

The issue is when the units/weight are negative numbers, they completely erase the previous values, so if the total units was 1200 and the next iteration is -5, suddenly the total is -5.

I though `5 + -2 = 3` in Python, I just can't figure out why this is happening, so I added the if statement and subtracted the `abs` value, but that isn't working either.

**EDIT**

Adding some data for reference

```
sku, name, units, weight
'548313', 'Product 2', '72', '0.3406'
'469981', 'Product 1', '936', '4.4268'
'469981', 'Product 1', '24', '0.1135'
'191004', 'Product 3', '480', '2.2700'
'469981', 'Product 1', '72', '0.3406'
'191004', 'Product 3', '576', '2.7242'
'212220', 'Product 4', '24', '0.1135'
'469981', 'Product 1', '624', '2.9511'
'469981', 'Product 1', '912', '4.3137'
'469981', 'Product 1', '-8', '-2.4000'
'548313', 'Product 2', '648', '3.0647'
'548313', 'Product 2', '48', '0.2270'
'548313', 'Product 2', '360', '1.7025'
'191004', 'Product 3', '24', '0.1135'
'191004', 'Product 3', '48', '0.2270'
'191004', 'Product 3', '456', '2.1567'
'817564', 'Product 6', '-1', '-0.3000'
'191004', 'Product 3', '576', '2.7242'
'212220', 'Product 4', '-1', '-0.3000'
'415116', 'Product 5', '480', '2.2703'
'415116', 'Product 5', '24', '0.1135'
'817564', 'Product 6', '48', '0.2270'
'548313', 'Product 2', '648', '3.0647'
```

Comment: Can you make a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: the default should be fresh with every iteration - it's not static, just contains other attributes other than the units and weight that need to be added to the dictionary for later retrieval

Comment: I've added some example data

Comment: I think the following is a string `products[item['sku']]['units']` which you are trying to subtract from. Cast it as an int before you operate on it. Don't use the -= in this case, rather use the long form and cast it as an int and subtract the abs(units) from it.

Comment: Why is it a string though? The values is cast as ```int```. Wouldn't the dictionary maintain the type?

Comment: I have run the code you've got above, and it seems to be working for me.

Comment: The only place I can observe the behaviour you've described is for product 6, but this is just because the negative -0.3 is the first case of a product 6.

Comment: Is it possible that since the raw data is coming from MariaDB that the ```-``` is interpreted differently in Python?

Comment: Side note, it might be worth using pandas instead of loops and dictionaries: pd.read_csv('val.csv').groupby('sku').sum() effectively yields your result

Comment: Data is from a database as a recordset. The CSV was simply to illustrate the dataset - sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured it out based on a comment that I believe was deleted. The odd calculations are cause by the `default` dictionary being set each time.

Once I replicated that dictionary creation to all the instances I was using the reference, it calculated accordingly.

I'm guessing this is a Python thing as from my experiences any variable within the scope of a loop gets re-initialized with the current value. This seems odd to me. Regardless, that's an entire day I'll never get back.